# Nokogiri - Checking if the value of an xpath exists and is blank or not in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I have an XML file, and before I process it I need to make sure that a certain element exists and is not blank.

Here is the code I have:

```
CSV.open("#{csv_dir}/products.csv","w",{:force_quotes => true}) do |out|
out << headers
Dir.glob("#{xml_dir}/*.xml").each do |xml_file|
gdsn_doc = GDSNDoc.new(xml_file)

logger.info("Processing xml file #{xml_file}")

:x
@desc_exists = @gdsn_doc.xpath("//productData/description")
 if !@desc_exists.empty?
  row = []
  headers.each do |col|
  row  << product[col]
end

 out << row
end
end
end
```

The following code is not working to find the "description" element and to check whether it is blank or not:

```
  @desc_exists = @gdsn_doc.xpath("//productData/description")
  if !@desc_exists.empty?
```

Here is a sample of the XML file:

```
<productData>

<description>Chocolate biscuits </description>

<productData>
```

This is how I have defined the class and Nokogiri:

```
class GDSNDoc
def initialize(xml_file)
   @doc =  File.open(xml_file) {|f| Nokogiri::XML(f)}
   @doc.remove_namespaces!
```

The code had to be moved up to an earlier stage, where Nokogiri was initialised. It doesn't get runtime errors, but it does let XML files with blank descriptions get through and it shouldn't.

```
class GDSNDoc
 def initialize(xml_file)
   @doc =  File.open(xml_file) {|f| Nokogiri::XML(f)}
   @doc.remove_namespaces!
   desc_exists = @doc.xpath("//productData/descriptions")
   if !desc_exists.empty?
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do you get an error or are the results not the one you expect?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention.
I get an error "undefined method 'xpath' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Don't put required information in comments, put it into the body of the question where it belongs, so people don't have to read every comment to understand what you're asking. Don't use "edit" or "update" tags; We can see what changed if we need to.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". Your code is full of syntax errors so Ruby won't try to run it. It also has undefined variables and classes. As a result there are a number of reasons for us to close it. Please review your question and code, and reduce the code to the bare minimum that duplicates the problem and meets the requirements. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421) will probably help you understand the effort needed.

Comment: As regards the "undefined variables and classes" it's because they are further up in the code. I only added the relevant part of the code to this question where I was getting the error - not the entire thing or it would be difficult for people to understand absolutely everything.

Comment: That's why you're supposed to strip everything not related. We expect you'll have done your due diligence and debugged and reduced until it's done to the essential code that _still duplicates the problem_. Anything beyond that wastes our time. You have to do that footwork then we help.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your instance like this:

```
gdsn_doc = GDSNDoc.new(xml_file)
```

then use it like this:

```
@desc_exists = @gdsn_doc.xpath("//productData/description")
```

`@gdsn_doc` and `gdsn_doc` are two different things in Ruby - try just using the version without the @:

```
@desc_exists = gdsn_doc.xpath("//productData/description")
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried that but I still get the same error.
"undefined method 'xpath' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"

Answer (score 0):

The basic test is to use:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<productData>
<description>Chocolate biscuits </description>
<productData>
EOT

# using XPath selectors...
doc.xpath('//productData/description').to_html # => "<description>Chocolate biscuits </description>"
doc.xpath('//description').to_html # => "<description>Chocolate biscuits </description>"
```

`xpath` works fine when the document is parsed correctly.

> I get an error "undefined method 'xpath' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Usually this means you didn't parse the document correctly. In your case it's because you're not using the right variable:

```
gdsn_doc = GDSNDoc.new(xml_file)
...
@desc_exists = @gdsn_doc.xpath("//productData/description")
```

Note that `gdsn_doc` is not the same as `@gdsn_doc`. The later doesn't appear to have been initialized.

---

> `@doc =  File.open(xml_file) {|f| Nokogiri::XML(f)}`

While that should work, it's idiomatic to write it as:

```
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.read(xml_file))
```

`File.open(...) do ... end` is preferred if you're processing inside the block and want Ruby to automatically close the file. That isn't necessary when you're simply reading then passing the content to something else for processing, hence the use of `File.read(...)` which slurps the file. (Slurping isn't necessary a good practice because it can have scalability problems, but for reasonable sized XML/HTML it's OK because it's easier to use DOM-based parsing than SAX.)

---

If Nokogiri doesn't raise an exception it was able to parse the content, however that still doesn't mean the content was valid. It's a good idea to check

```
@doc.errors
```

to see whether Nokogiri/libXML had to do some fix-ups on the content just to be able to parse it. Fixing the markup can change the DOM from what you expect, making it impossible to find a tag based on your assumptions for the selector. You could use `xmllint` or one of the XML validators to check, but Nokogiri will still have to be happy.

Nokogiri includes a command-line version `nokogiri` that accepts a URL to the document you want to parse:

```
nokogiri http://example.com
```

It'll open IRB with the content loaded and ready for you to poke at it. It's very convenient when debugging and testing. It's also a decent way to make sure the content actually exists if you're dealing with HTML containing DHTML that loads parts of the page dynamically.

Comment: Using "gdsn_doc" instead of "@gdsn_doc" doesn't work - I still get the same error.

Comment: I will add to the description how I have defined the class and Nokogiri